# Expect not accepting negative values

Tags: expect

I am trying to run `expect` with negative values. But I'm getting bad flag error.

Test File:

```
echo "Enter Number:"
read num
echo $num
```

Expect File:

```
spawn sh test.sh
expect -- "Enter Number:" {send "-342345"}
```

I even tried to escape negative values with `\` option still it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this as well

```
# cat expectscript
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sh test.sh
expect "Enter Number:" {send -- "-2394\r"}
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ cat test.sh
echo "Enter number"
read num
echo $num
```

and

```
$ cat test.exp 
spawn sh test.sh
set value "-342345"
expect "Enter number" {
    send -- "$value\r"
}
interact
```

Run above command as

```
$ expect test.exp
```